# Application Error. There was a network error. (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files

Tags: html, intel-xdk

I have a problem with starting other pages in the project. Index.html starts fine. This seems to have appeared after the recent upgrade to Intel XDk. 1826. I may be wrong about this. I typically have a normal App Framework application and I then add addition pages. My pages are separate html pages. In my example I have the normal generated index.html page then I also have a login.html page. I have tried starting the page with both javascript button: window.location.href = 'login.html'; and with html button:

In both cases I now get an Application Error. When using App Preview, the error is:

> Application Error. There was a network error. (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/YqWWub....../4.0.0/login.html

When running as an installed app and I have tried on a second device the error is:

> Application Error. The web page contains an error. (file:///android_asset?www/login.html.

This however runs perfectly in the emulator. How I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are running into "whitelist" or cross-domain problems with your other pages. It is best to build a single-page app when building Cordova apps (you are creating a standard Cordova app when you use the Intel XDK). When you switch to a new page you lose the JavaScript context that provides the connection to the underlying Cordova native layer you need to make the whole thing work. Multi-page apps can be made to work, but it's generally a lot of hassle and not the recommended way to build Cordova apps.

Please see [this Cordova doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_next_index.md.html#Next%20Steps) for more background.